# Replacing wp_query value

Tags: wordpress

I have a site that uses a custom query to search for posts by country.

The search results come back fine, but the pagination at the bottom reflects the total number of posts in the site, instead of the total number of posts in the search results.

The plug in that manages this uses global $wp_query to determine the number of posts, instead of the custom query. By default, it works like this:

```
function wp_page_numbers($start = "", $end = "")
{
    global $wp_query;
    global $max_page;
    global $paged;
    if ( !$max_page ) { $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages; }
    if ( !$paged ) { $paged = 1; }

    $settings = get_option('wp_page_numbers_array');
    $page_of_page = $settings["page_of_page"];
    $page_of_page_text = $settings["page_of_page_text"];
    $page_of_of = $settings["page_of_of"];

    $next_prev_text = $settings["next_prev_text"];
    $show_start_end_numbers = $settings["show_start_end_numbers"];
    $show_page_numbers = $settings["show_page_numbers"];

    $limit_pages = $settings["limit_pages"];
    $nextpage = $settings["nextpage"];
    $prevpage = $settings["prevpage"];
    $startspace = $settings["startspace"];
    $endspace = $settings["endspace"];

    if( $nextpage == "" ) { $nextpage = "&gt;"; }
    if( $prevpage == "" ) { $prevpage = "&lt;"; }
    if( $startspace == "" ) { $startspace = "..."; }
    if( $endspace == "" ) { $endspace = "..."; }

    if($limit_pages == "") { $limit_pages = "10"; }
    elseif ( $limit_pages == "0" ) { $limit_pages = $max_page; }
```

I tried modifying it to this:

```
if ($gallery_query){ $page_query=$gallery_query; }else {$page_query=$wp_query;}
    global $max_page;
    global $paged;
    if ( !$max_page ) { $max_page = $page_query->max_num_pages; }
    if ( !$paged ) { $paged = 1; }
```

But that returns no pages.

Ideally, I should replace the $wp_query value  with the $gallery_query value, but I don't know how. The obvious `$wp_query = $gallery_query` doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

ty

Comment: `if ($gallery_query)` will check to see if the value of $gallery_query exists. Are you sure that is what you want? Just change the if condition to something with which you can verify the query you will need is gallery_query. BTW, if the correct results are displayed, you might not need to edit this. Where is the code where the total number of search results if outputted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [TheDeadMedic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1685/thedeadmedic) for this:

```
function wp_page_numbers_custom( $wp_query, $start = '', $end = '' )
{
    $_backup = array(
        'wp_query' => @ $GLOBALS['wp_query'],
        'max_page' => @ $GLOBALS['max_page'],
           'paged' => @ $GLOBALS['paged'],  
    );

    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $wp_query;
    $GLOBALS['max_page'] = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
       $GLOBALS['paged'] = max( $wp_query->get( 'paged' ), 1 );

    wp_page_numbers( $start, $end );

    foreach ( $_backup as $var => $val )
        $GLOBALS[ $var ] = $val;
}

// Example usage: wp_page_numbers_custom( $gallery_query );
```

It totally solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with the WP Page Numbers Plugin. Another solution to the problem is to modify the $wp_query for your search results then do a wp_reset_query if you need to go back to the original.